# ¿How to Select Column cells except last with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Im rendering a table with dynamic data via **JSON**, i need to select all the cells except the **THE LAST ONE**, because im going to make some calculations. Is any selector or function to solve this problem?

**HTML**

```
    <tbody id="tiempo_plan_table1">
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td >
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td > </td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td >
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td >
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td >Result</td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td >
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>                                       
    </tbody>
```

**I FOUND THIS SOLUTION**

```
$("tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").filter("td:not(:last)").css("background", "CornflowerBlue")
```

Comment: 1) Add a class to the `<td>` that contains your buttons. 2) Select all `td` elements except the last by using `not()` paired with the class from step 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to solve the problem....

```
$("tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").filter("td:not(:last)").css("background", "CornflowerBlue")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector

```
$("tbody tr td:not(:last-child)").addClass("background");
```

```js
$("tbody tr td:not(:last-child)").addClass("background");
```

```css
.background {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tiempo_plan_table1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <button>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <button>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <button>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Result</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <button>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hey satpal, i need to select the 3 col and show result on last cell (dynamycally), thats why im using nth-child(3), but with that code i select the last too and i dont want to select the last because in the last ill show the result